# How can I get the value of %vsspv_visualstudio_dir% variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

VS2015 Update 3

In my external application I need to get the `User project templates location` and `User item templates location` settings values for VS2015. Then I will add my templates into that directories.

[image]

The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Profile\AutoSaveFile` parameter contains the `%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings` value.

[image]

Inside of that file the necessary values also contains the `%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%` variable:

```
<PropertyValue name="ProjectTemplatesLocation">%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Templates\ProjectTemplates</PropertyValue>  
<PropertyValue name="ProjectItemTemplatesLocation">%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Templates\ItemTemplates</PropertyValue>
```

How can I expand the `%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%` variable? 
The `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(String)` method can't expand it:

```
var str = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
    "%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%"); // I get the same string
```

Comment: What about HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\UserProjectTemplatesLocation registry key? It also contains path to that templates folder, without strange variables.

Comment: But the `PropertyValue` xml-items of `vssettings`-file which are necessary to me contain that variable too.

Comment: You mean you need more than project and items template locations? Because both of those seems to be present in related keys under 14.0 registry branch.

Comment: @Evk, thank you. Are these parameters always contain the values of current profile VS2015? Or maybe they have the default values?

Comment: If I update project templates location in settings sections shown on your first screenshot - the value in registry changes too. So I guess that yes, they have values of current profile.

Comment: Thank you. Can you post your answer as answer? At this case I will mark it as decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locations of project and item templates folder for current VS2015 user profile can also be found in the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\UserProjectTemplatesLocation
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\UserItemTemplatesLocation
```

Those values do not contain any variables and so can be used as is.

Answer (score 0):

A other problem and his solution. This post was the tipp for to solution - thanks.

The variable `%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%` is associated by default with the default directory "Documents".

Problem: If the default directory "Documents" does not exists (because it was removed via registry, wasn't a good idea), so the settings are not accepted or saved in MS VS Setting, Projects and Solutions, Locations. Next new start of MS VS lost this setting.

Solution: Restore default directory "Documents".

Test: MS VS reseting section "General" to default setting without fault.

It was a long way to find out why the MS VS Setting is not saved.