# VS2017: How can I get the value of %vsspv_visualstudio_dir% variable?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[This decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190340/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-vsspv-visualstudio-dir-variable) doesn't work for Visual Studio 2017: registry doesn't contain this info.

How can I expand the `%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%` variable of VisualStudio 2017?

Comment: link for "This decision" is missing.

Comment: [VS2017 uses a private registry file](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2017/07/15/about-the-new-privateregistry-bin-file-of-visual-studio-2017/) instead of the real registry